# AngularJS nested states using stateProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

I am trying to implement nested states using stateProvider. Facing issues while loading the nested states using url-routing. I have created two independent states and 2 nested states for one of the inndependent state. Please check the state configuration below:

```
.state('state1',{
         url : "/page1",
         templateUrl : "/views/page1.html",
         contoller : 'page1ctrl'
})
.state('state2', {
         url : "/page2",
         templateUrl : "/views/page2.html",
         controller : 'page2ctrl'
})
state('state2.nestedstate1', {
         url : "/:nestedstate1",  //passing as parameter
         templateUrl : "/views/temp1.html",
         controller : 'page2ctrl'
})
.state('state2.nestedstate1.nestedstate2', {
         url : "/nestedstate2/:param1/:param2",
         templateUrl : "/views/temp2.html",
         controller : 'ctrl'
})
```

Issue : If I try to load complete page directly using complete url `index.html/page2/nestedstate1/nestedstate2/fname/lname`, it will first load data from last child state *nestedstate2* and then fall back to its parent state '*nestedstate1*' and also updates the url to `index.html/page2/nestedstate1`.

Required behaviour is to execute parent state first then the child state. For Example, nestedstate1 is necessary to load before nestedstate2.

Please suggest if I am missing any configuration.

Thanks

Comment: definitely need to produce a plnkr or fiddle for this. UI Router is fairly complex.

Comment: I will post one plnkr soon. Working on it.

Comment: Meanwhile, if anybody is facing same issue. Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I created [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OMXscS4VlrebY540o27?p=preview). It is 1:1 to your scenario.

In the above script I found only one typo:

```
// missing dot
state('state2.nestedstate1', {
// should be 
.state('state2.nestedstate1', {
```

The example is then working, while using these calls:

```
  <a ui-sref="state1">

  // ui-sref
  <a ui-sref="state2">
  <a ui-sref="state2.nestedstate1({nestedstate1: 'theNestedStateA'})">
  <a ui-sref="state2.nestedstate1.nestedstate2({
  nestedstate1: 'theNestedStateB', param1: 'value1' ,param2: 'value2'})">

  // href
  <a href="#/page2">
  <a href="#/page2/nestedstate0">
  <a href="#/page2/nestedstate1/nestedstate2/fname/lname">
```

All the rest should be almost the same. You can compare this working version with your local code, to find out what is wrong...

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OMXscS4VlrebY540o27?p=preview)

Extend

Each view in (state2 chain) is provided with its own controller

```
.state('state2', {
     url : "/page2",
     templateUrl : "/views/page2.html",
     controller : 'page2ctrl'
})
.state('state2.nestedstate1', {
     url : "/:nestedstate1",  //passing as parameter
     templateUrl : "/views/temp1.html",
     controller : 'page2Nestedctrl'
})
.state('state2.nestedstate1.nestedstate2', {
     url : "/nestedstate2/:param1/:param2",
     templateUrl : "/views/temp2.html",
     controller : 'ctrl'
})
```

And they are like this:

```
.controller('page2ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  console.log('page2ctrl')
}])
.controller('page2Nestedctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  console.log('page2Nestedctrl')
}])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { 
  console.log('ctrl')
}])
```

Then when navigating to url: **`page2/nestedstate1/nestedstate2/fname/lname`**, we can see this in console:

```
page2ctrl
page2Nestedctrl
ctrl
```

And that should show, that all the states are initiated in expected order

Comment: This was just a typo, I don't have this issue in my working code.
Fortunately I have resolved the issue, there was one extra call ($state.go('parent')) in controller to parent state which was rendering parent again.

Comment: You should check my plunker, becuase you did not shiped any. And that will give you your answers. I updated functionality and the anwer. Good luck with UI-Router

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into and creating a plunker. I have resolved the issue with my app.

Comment: Haleluja. That sounds great ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router